# How can I apply styles to an ancestor using scss? Only if the ancestor has x element/class?

Tags: sass, parent-selector

If a `.page-builder__item--text` has a table in it I want it to take on x styles.

From reading the sass-lang docs I've got this but this doesn't seem to work.
Have I misunderstood the docs? If so how?
Note: I can't change the html

```
table {
  .page-builder__item--text & {
    background-attachment: red;
  }
}
```

the html looks like this

```
<div class="page-builder__item--text">
    <div class="no-leftpad no-rightpad">
        <div class="pb-text">
           <table>
   //====table content here
           </table>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a CSS parent selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector)

Answer (score 0):

There's no way to select ancestors in CSS or SCSS. If the table is full width and height you could target the ::after element to add a background.

Otherwise I recommend javascript.

Comment: background was just an example, I actually want to put overflow-x: scroll on it at screen. Can you send me in the right direction on your javascript recommendation? Or is there a better solution? I can't have all .page-builder__item--text with an overflow-x: scroll, only ones with tables inside them